# Try to insert date by C# into .accdb but the data went wrong

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I'm tried to run this sql

```
insert into Registration (sn, regDate) values ('RS5044737',Format('2021/06/15 10:22:20', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:nn:ss'));
```

but in my .accdb file, data went wrong like this :

[image]

I have no idea why the year become 1478......

enviriment:

C# 2008

Access 2007

Comment: As an aside, 2008 is a particularly prehistoric version of VS - any reason why you don't upgrade to 2019? It's a much nicer development experience

Comment: This problem is from a program which developed a decade ago and updating ceased.
It has been used in many nations for years and this problem never happened ,until one new client join recently.

Comment: So, it's been wrong for 10 years :) ... *this problem never happened* - having been wrong so long doesn't mean it's only just causing a problem, it simply means that it's causing a problem for someone willing to report it. Also doesn't mean that it doesn't need fixing - good job you're invested in doing *something* about it :)

Answer (score 5):

Won't happen if you use parameters

```
insert into Registration (sn, regDate) values (?, ?);
```

And

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("n", "RS5044737");
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("d", new DateTime(2021,6,15,10,22,20));
```

Add parameters in the same order the ? appear in the statement.

Always, always use parameters. It prevents:

- data errors like you're getting
- random crashes if you try to insert apostrophes into eg people's names
- you getting fired for causing [massive breaches of security](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vtech+hack&t=h_&ia=web)

If you upgrade to SQLserver, switch away from using [AddWithValue](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) (but always use parameters)

Answer (score 1):

MM in uppercase is Month format.
mm in lowercase is minute.

insert into Registration (sn, regDate) values ('RS5044737',Format('2021/06/15 10:22:20', 'yyyy/**MM**/dd hh:**mm**:ss'));

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your format string is wrong.

What I'm using to make SQL **date and time** strings is this method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Formats a date time value so that it fits the JET specification
/// for date formats to be usable from within a SQL query.
/// The format is #MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS# (including the hashs).
/// </summary>
public static string FormatJetDateAndTime(
    DateTime dateToFormat)
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
        @"#{0:00}/{1:00}/{2} {3:00}:{4:00}:{5:00}#",
        dateToFormat.Month,
        dateToFormat.Day,
        dateToFormat.Year,
        dateToFormat.Hour,
        dateToFormat.Minute,
        dateToFormat.Second);
}
```

To format date only, I'm using this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Formats the date portion of a date time value so that it fits into
/// the JET specification for date formats to be usable from within a SQL query.
/// The format is #MM/DD/YYYY# (including the hashs).
/// </summary>
public static string FormatJetDateOnly(
    DateTime dateToFormat)
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
        @"#{0:00}/{1:00}/{2}#",
        dateToFormat.Month,
        dateToFormat.Day,
        dateToFormat.Year);
}
```

And to format **time** only, I'm using this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Formats the time portion of a date time value so that it fits into
/// the JET specification for date formats to be usable from within a SQL query.
/// The format is #HH:MM:SS# (including the hashs).
/// </summary>
public static string FormatJetTimeOnly(
    DateTime dateToFormat)
{
    return string.Format(
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
        @"#{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}#",
        dateToFormat.Hour,
        dateToFormat.Minute,
        dateToFormat.Second);
}
```

Of course, using parameterized queries as [Caius Jard points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68093797/107625) is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

To insert a fixed value using Access SQL, use *octothorpes*:

```
insert into Registration (sn, regDate) values ('RS5044737',#2021/06/15 10:22:20#);
```

But, most likely, the date value will not be fixed, so use parameters as shown by Caius - only use `Add` and `Value`, not `AddWithValue`.

Comment: What's wrong with AddWithValue for an insert statement in Access?

Comment: @CaiusJard: That you don't get familiar with the other syntax.

Comment: Mmm.. I see the point, but it's not a strong one; to be honest I'd rather everyone everywhere parameterized with AddWithValue for everything and 1% of the time came complaining "This select statement in my SQL Server runs like a dog", than didn't parameterize and 99% of the time came complaining "my site is constantly getting hacked by script kiddies". MySQL even go as far as to say "Use AddWithValue" so I don't make a blanket "don't use it, use this harder to remember, less convenient way" rule of it, because people just.. won't. Getting them to parameterize at all would be a much bigger win

Comment: @CaiusJard: OK, can agree on that. Didn't know about the MySql recommendation, thanks.